# Receiving errors with simple Python code, confused as to why. ActiveCode provides a whole other error

Tags: python, syntax-error

Here is the code to finding out a grade from a mark, pretty simple:

```
def grading(grade):
    n = (grade)
    
    if n >= 90:
        return "A"
    else:
        if n >= 80 and n < 90:
            return "B"
        else:
            if n >= 70 and n < 80:
                return "C"
            else:
                if n >= 60 and n < 70:
                    return "D"
                else:
                    return "F"
                 
m = float(input("What is your number grade?"))

print("Mark:", str(grade), "Grade:", grading(m))
```

I am getting a **"SyntaxError: bad input on line 22"** when running it

& the site I'm using (**interactivepython.org**) has an **activecode** function where it follows the code step by step and that produces the error of `"IndentationError: unexpected indent (<string>, line 1)"`

Comment: there's an error in your print statement as `grade` is out of scope (it's only in scope for the `grading` function. Otherwise this looks like it should execute without error.

Comment: `grade` is not defined, print `str(m)`

Comment: You should do this with `if/elif` statements rather than nested `if` statements.

Comment: @DavidZemens Not 'should', 'can'...

Comment: Sorry yeah i switched between m and grade variables a few times. But sticking with m, i changed it to print(str(m)) and its still not working

Comment: @officialaimm is there a good reason to nest successive `if/else/if` statements when the conditions are mutually exclusive? If not, then *should*.

Comment: @DavidZemens `If\else\if` though not optimal can be fruitful for beginners to understand the decision-process more easily. Of course `elifs` are easy to write and optimized,

Comment: adding onto my previous comment, the code functions fine in codelens but still has the syntaxerror with the regular activecode

Comment: @DavidZemens  how does the 'if/elif' work

Comment: @NibrasAlam There seems to be a problem with the online interpreter/site whatever you are using. [Because this code seems to work fine. You can  verify it here](https://tio.run/##bZE5DsIwEEV7n2I0NLZEgRC7WMQiqKipDXbAInGiiVPk9CEJSxxgGlvv@7/Ck@TuFtt@USgdwJWkMvbKq1OLGYNyLCzgBVgNTFCy5QKmveeDaki7jCzgGmukw1Q34bsw6YG0qrzPW12/v8EPbjt8z7jxTL48vmuLrejX5ztHjXP8x@l7d/gT/3f7pT0yFpU/GYSxdNzYJHMcTzfpwKSQxxmBzaKzpnoFeoVCsISMdVxARyqlFQQxwSWUZFz@ivAo6T7DLqSOeCS6gIeqXJH3IiMhoCgGwwc "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @NibrasAlam too long to explain in comments so I added an "answer" that you can review to see how that works.

Comment: It's better to get in that habit of using `if/elif`, especially when writing larger conditionals, it can get very error-prone when having to remember where to indent/deindent

Comment: Or use a dictionary

Comment: okay thanks everyone!!! makes sense now. one last question: would using a int instead of a float conversion be beneficial?

Comment: if you don't need decimal precision, then use `int`. Do you understand the differences between them? If not, maybe brush up on the subject...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Won't fit in comments, but here is the `if/elif` construct.

```
def grading(grade):
    if grade >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif grade >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif grade >= 70:
        return "C"
    elif grade >= 60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

m = float(input("What is your number grade?"))

print("Mark:", str(m), "Grade:", grading(m))
```

[Visualize it](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20grading%28grade%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20grade%20%3E%3D%2090%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22A%22%0A%20%20%20%20elif%20grade%20%3E%3D%2080%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22B%22%0A%20%20%20%20elif%20grade%20%3E%3D%2070%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22C%22%0A%20%20%20%20elif%20grade%20%3E%3D%2060%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22D%22%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22F%22%0A%0Am%20%3D%20float%28input%28%22What%20is%20your%20number%20grade%3F%22%29%29%0A%0Aprint%28%22Mark%3A%22,%20str%28m%29,%20%22Grade%3A%22,%20grading%28m%29%29%20&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

The decision process is the same, the second half of the conditions (e.g., `if grade >= 80 and grade < 90` is unnecessary, because we've already guaranteed that `grade < 90` by falling to this point in the decision tree: If grade is greater than or equal to 90, none of the `elif` blocks will execute. If it is less than 90, only *one* of the `elif` blocks will execute, so there is no need to test both bounds of the range, just check against the min.